# Unable to download facebook app, though having a new SD card

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have an android gt9000 and I'm getting very frustrated because it won't let me download the facebook app and it keeps saying insufficient storage available but I only have one app downloaded and I have a brand new SD card in it.

Comment: Click [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) to see similar questions (might have useful answer for you) under the tag [tag:insufficient-memory].

Comment: How do I remove bloatware? What is that even?

Comment: Bloatwares are the apps shipped by your OEM in your device in addition to core Android apps. E.g. You might be having some Samsung related apps (by default) in your device which you can't remove but only disable; that's what is known as bloatware. Some consider those apps as bloatware which are mostly useless to a user. Anyhow, they are system apps (supposed to be user apps) and can be removed only after rooting your device. You can use an app like [System apps Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.system.app&hl=en)(root required) to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Android system and data storage is different partition. Are you sure only 1 app downloaded? Try to move your app to sd card from setting or if you have root access try to uninstall bloatware that came with your phone.

Comment: IDT removing bloatware will lessen the gravity of the issue here. User installed apps are in `/data` while bloatwares are in `/system`.

Comment: @Firelord and the data of the `/system/` apps are in `/data/data/`

Comment: True! I forgot that.  However, why uninstall when you can disable and clear data of any bloatware.